# How pass data with socket between two separated computers

Tags: c#, sockets, console-application

In my job I need to get data from another company using sockets, so I tried firstly using only my pc as server and client. When I use localhost or my IPv4 all works great, but when I use my public IP it crashes with this error:

> the requested address is not valid in its context public

So how can I achieved this?

This is my code

**Client**

```
onnection:
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1302);
            string messageToSend = "My name is Neo";

            int byteCount = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(messageToSend + 1);
            byte[] sendData = new byte[byteCount];
            sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageToSend);

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            stream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Sending data to server...");

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            string response = sr.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(response);

            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect...");
            goto connection;
        }
```

**Server**

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1302);
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection");
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Client accepted");
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                int recv = 0;
                foreach(byte b in buffer)
                {
                    if(b != 0)
                    {
                        recv++;
                    }
                }
                string request = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, recv);
                Console.WriteLine("request received: " + request);
                sw.WriteLine("Recibido");
                sw.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong...");
                sw.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: If that code works on the same computer with your local IP address, then there is likely nothing wrong with your code, and instead you have a networking or firewall problem. Unfortunately, we can't really help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be hardcoding the loopback address 127.0.0.1 as the required IP address,but this will not work outside of your own machine. You should be accepting a TCP packet from any address,System.Net.IPAddres.Any,  on that specific port.